# Ionic framework cannot set button icon size

Tags: css, icons, ionic-framework

I would like to set custom icon (ionicons) size for this code:

```
<button class="button button-icon icon ion-stop customIconSound"></button>
```

For class **customIconSound** i tried following:

```
button.customIconSound,button.button-icon {
    font-size: 52px !important;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 55px!important;
}
```

But without luck. If i tried icon class without the **button button-icon** class i fount that it is working but without button class icons has not pressed state (because is it not a button).

How can i solve it please?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 15):

Lucas was close but the correct syntax is this one

```
button.customIconSound:before {
    font-size: 22px !important;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thx!  

@Vandervidi Replace "customIconSound" with the class name of your element and it should work.

Answer (score 6):

If you didn`t solve your problem yet or for people dealing with it in future.

You have to change css style for i pseudo element :before

```
button.customIconSound i:before {
    font-size: 52px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your example is working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LgXNl94QOx6oDlN7hc9V?p=preview).

Maybe your problem is caused by something else.

PS: If you want only to resize the icon this css line is enough.

```
.customIconSound {
    font-size: 52px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ruling `button-icon` class out. That css class was the trouble in my case. Likewise, as a result, css styles worked on button tag too. For example:

```
<button class="button button-clear ion-edit" style="color:#fff; font-size:22px"></button>
```